# jQuery - Add a string to textbox if more than one checkbox is checked and for each checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, checkbox, textbox

I have over 25 check-boxes. So far I have it when an item is check the value goes inside a textbox.  What I am trying to do is... After the first check box is check and it is value is then entered in a textbox below... Everything else checked needs to add a string of " AND " before each value that is checked. My script is below...

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var lastChecked;
            var $checks = $('input:checkbox').click(function(e) {
                var numChecked = $checks.filter(':checked').length;
                    if (numChecked > 1 ) {
                        $(":checkbox:checked").each(function(){
                            var text = $('#text_query');
                            text.val(' AND' + text.val());
                    });                                 
                }
                lastChecked = this;
            });
        }); 
    </script>
```

The problem that I am having is all the "And"s are all showing up in front of all products and I am recieving an extra "AND" from the first product I checked inside a text box.    Example

AND AND AND Product_1 Product_2 Product_3

It should look like this...

Product_1 AND Product_2 AND Product_3

So what Am I missing.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you please share your html or a fiddle, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had some incorrect logic dealing with your `AND` appending. Take a look below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var lastChecked;
  var $checks = $('input:checkbox').click(function(e) {
    var numChecked = $checks.filter(':checked').length;
    var text = $('#text_query');
    text.val('');
    $(":checkbox:checked").each(function() {
      console.log($(this).val());
      text.val($(this).val() + ' AND ' + text.val());
    });
    var str = text.val();
    text.val(str.substring(0, str.length - 4));
    lastChecked = this;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" value="3">
<input type="checkbox" value="4">
<input type="checkbox" value="5">
<input type="checkbox" value="6">
<input type="checkbox" value="7">
<input type="checkbox" value="8">
<input type="checkbox" value="9">
<br/>
<input type="text" id="text_query">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    var text = $('#text_query');
     text.val(text.val('AND'));
```